# Google maps map icons are flickering in swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

I am working with google maps in swift. Everything works fine. I am stuck while updating marker in the map, other icons are shaking for example buildings ,restaurants etc.,these are also animating. Please some one guide me why this happens?

Comment: I'm too using google map with swift 3. its working fine here with annotation.

Comment: And the thing is I don't set anything for that. all default behavior.

Comment: I am using two apps , when my location changes in driver app, it will be updated in tracker app.

Comment: I shall update you if I find anything for you.

Comment: @AshwinIndianic.. how & where ur setting default behaviour in app.

Comment: I mean I just set mapview to my targeted view and add its delegate methods for annotation view and its tap, by setting pins one map loaded.That is all what i did and working as expected

Comment: @AshwinIndianic. Is there any issue with key i am not using iOS-restricted API key

Comment: No, As keys are used to authenticate/Identify the app/user.

Comment: @AshwinIndianic. Are u aware of markers in google maps. I am trying to rotate the marker position, but i am not able to achieve

Comment: Its same like annotations in Apple map. What do you mean by rotate the marker?

Comment: @AshwinIndianic. For example i have Car image in google when user travels in left or right means the position should be updated.

Comment: When you drop multiple pins on same lat/long pins will be flickering. Add single pin on single lat/long. Which may be help you to solve it.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I am also seeing same issue. Are you able to resolve same?

Comment: @Samkit Jain . Still the issue exist . I could not able to resolve